# typescript: get the type of basic class in interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a basic class just like

```
class Animal {

}
```

and I have two child class like

```
class Dog extends Animal {}
class Bird extends Animal {}
```

Now, I want to define an interface include the Animal class, like

```
interface Zoo{
  name: string;
  animal: Animal;
}
```

and use it

```
const myZoo: Zoo = {
  name: 'zooName',
  animal: Dog  // problem is here
}
```

let it be, I failed. So, what should i do? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your interface with `typeof` operator

```
interface Zoo {
   name: string;
   animal: typeof Animal;
}
```

This is a [**DEMO**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Animal%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Dog%20extends%20Animal%20%7B%20constructor()%20%7B%20super()%3B%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Bird%20extends%20Animal%20%7B%20constructor()%20%7B%20super()%3B%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Zoo%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20animal%3A%20typeof%20Animal%3B%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myZoo1%3A%20Zoo%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'zooName'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20animal%3A%20Dog%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(new%20myZoo1.animal())%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myZoo2%3A%20Zoo%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'zooName'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20animal%3A%20Bird%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(new%20myZoo2.animal())%3B).

Comment: that's good, but i want to `new Dog()` in other places, like `new myZoo.animal()`. So i can't `new Dog()` in here, right?

Comment: Thank you very much. And  I'm so stupid. I tried your method just recently, and i found that one of myZoo.animal is not `extends Animal`...